# Meu cálculo de subtração em JavaScript está retornando um "NaN"

Tags: javascript, conversão-de-tipo

Sou iniciante em JavaScript e eu tava fazendo um programinha de cálculo de troco. Usei o seguinte código:

```html
<h1>Calculando o Troco</h1>
<input type="button" value="Comprar produto" onclick="clique()">
<script>
  function clique(){
    var produto = prompt('Qual produto você quer comprar?')
    var custo = parseFloat(prompt(`Quanto custa o(a) ${produto} que você está comprando?`)).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')
    var valor = parseFloat(prompt(`Qual foi o valor que você deu para pagar o(a) ${produto}?`)).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')
    var troco = parseFloat(valor - custo).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')
    alert(`Você comprou um(a) ${produto} que custou R$ ${custo}. Você deu R$ ${valor} em dinheiro e vai receber R$ ${troco} de troco. Volte sempre!`)
  }
</script>
```

Quando executado, o `alert` mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> Você comprou um(a) pão que custou R$ 5,00. Você deu R$ 10,00 em dinheiro e vai receber R$ `NaN` de troco.

Ja tentei sem o `parseFloat`, sem o `replace`, fazendo o cálculo dentro do *placeholder*, mas nada funciona.

O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado! :)

Comment: Acho que vale uma explicacao um pouco melhor que um simples comentario. Coloquei uma respota e espero que ajude vc :)

Answer (score 3):

Acontece que a subtração dos valores consegue fazer o *parse* ambas strings (`valor` e `custo`) que segue o formato `0.00` (por exemplo) ou string que tem formato de número inteiro `'0'`. Ele consegue identificar o `.` do número com ponto flutuante.

No caso, o `prompt` retorna uma string, e essa conversão que você usa faz sentido, até porque realmente devemos tratar qualquer dado que seja de entrada, principalmente de usuário, mas isso fica pra outra hora.

Veja abaixo:

```js
// string de um número flutuante
const str = '2.88'

// exibe o número 2.88 e o tipo é "number"
console.log(parseFloat(str), typeof parseFloat(str))
```

Agora, quando você usou o `toFixed(2)`, foi feita uma conversão de tipo `'number'` para `'string'`. Veja o exemplo para a string `'2'`:

```js
let value = parseFloat('2')

// antes era "number"
console.log(value, typeof value)

// agora converteu para "string" por causa do toFixed
value = value.toFixed(2)

console.log(value, typeof value)
```

O problema do `NaN` foi por causa do `replace('.', ',')`. Uma ou mais string que tinha o formato `'2.00'` pode ser facilmente aceita pela operação de subtração, **uma vez que o `-` converte ambas as strings em números**, logo algo como `'2.00'` é entendido como ponto flutuante `2.00` depois de convertido, porém o `'2,00'` não é por causa da `,`:

```js
let value = parseFloat('2').toFixed(2)

// antes era "2.00"
console.log(value)

// agora transformou '2.00' em '2,00'
value = value.replace('.', ',')
console.log(value)

// aqui eu demonstro que '2.00' - '2.00'
// funciona normalmente

// ambos sao convertidos para numeros
console.log('2.00' - '2.00')

// agora '2,00' é entendido como string
// não possível de ser convertida em número,
// logo essa operação de subtração irá falhar.

// ocorre um erro por causa do '2,00' e retorna
// NaN
console.log('2,00' - '2.00')
```

No seu caso, o uso do `replace` antes da hora, ocasionou o erro. Tente aprender desde cedo que o que você fez foi formatar um resultado para exibir para o usuário, isso deve ser, geralmente, **o último passo** no tratamento de valores, ou seja, você deveria realizar todas as operações e somente no fim, tratar os dados e exibí-los no formato que o usuário espera.

Remova o `replace` dos valores de `custo` e `valor`, faça as operações necessárias primeiro, e por fim, formate para exibir o resultado:

```html
<h1>Calculando o Troco</h1>
<input type="button" value="Comprar produto" onclick="clique()">
<script>
  function clique(){
    var produto = prompt('Qual produto você quer comprar?')
    
    // remova replace
    var custo = parseFloat(prompt(`Quanto custa o(a) ${produto} que você está comprando?`)).toFixed(2)
    var valor = parseFloat(prompt(`Qual foi o valor que você deu para pagar o(a) ${produto}?`)).toFixed(2)
    
    // realize a opercao valor - custo primeiro   
    var troco = parseFloat(valor - custo).toFixed(2)
    
    // depois formate o valor para exibir
    // deixe o código um pouco mais semantico
    var trocoFormatado = troco.replace('.', ',')
    
    alert(`Você comprou um(a) ${produto} que custou R$ ${custo}. Você deu R$ ${valor} em dinheiro e vai receber R$ ${trocoFormatado} de troco. Volte sempre!`)
  }
</script>
```